# Android java.lang.VerifyError on static method call

Tags: java, android, static, verifyerror

I developed my application and when it runs on Android 4.4 I have no problem and all works fine. If I start my application on Android 4.2 and I call a static method like this:

```
double value = Utility.parseDouble(editValue.getText().toString().trim());
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/mycompany/myapp/util/Utility
        at com.mycompany.myapp.activity.MainActivity.updateMerchantInfo(MainActivity.java:112)
        at com.mycompany.myapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.5.9'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.6'
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Please help me!

**EDIT**
I solved my issue! The problem was caused by a method into the Utility class:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private static void copyFieldValue(Object src, Object dest, Field f) {
    try {
        Object value = f.get(src);
        f.set(dest, value);
    } catch ( ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Got the same error and was able to fix it. In my case the Problem was a wrong configured multidex.

My configuration worked on >= Android 5.0 devices and failed on the earlier ones.

To make it short, here is the configuration which finally worked for me.

1.) First of all go to your build.gradle (module app) and add the following line
inside your defaultConfig:

**multiDexEnabled true**

example:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.multidex"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2.a) If you´re not extending Application, go to your manifest and change the name of application to      **android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"**

example:

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    .. >
 ..
</application>
```

2.b) if you´re extending application and your name is already looking like this:
     android:name=".App"

go to your class which extends Application and change it to extends **MultiDexApplication**

example:

public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your gradle file and don't forget to clean your project before build.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already tried to add this block but it doesn't fix my problem. I suppose the problem is due to a library that makes use of annotation.